# Утечка памяти при обновлении уведомления

Tags: android, уведомления, утечка-памяти

**Задача:** В панели уведомлений выводить оставшееся количество секунд до определённого момента.

**Пришёл к:** Имеется `Service`, который выводит уведомление с оставшимся количеством секунд до определённого действия. Код сервиса:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service
    {

        Timer NotificationCounter;
        TimerTask NotificationCounterTask;

        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        int Timecount = 1000; //Начальное количество секунд

        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon) //Картинка
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setColor(Color.rgb(76, 229, 76))
                    .setAutoCancel(false);
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            NotificationCounter = new Timer();

            startForeground(1,builder.build());
        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {

            NotificationCounter = new Timer();
            NotificationCounterTask = new explainNotificationTimerTask();
            NotificationCounter.schedule(NotificationCounterTask, 1000, 1000);

            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        //Расписываем действие счётчика
        private class explainNotificationTimerTask extends TimerTask
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                Timecount = Timecount - 1; //Ведём отсчёт

                if ( Timecount >= 0)
                {
                    builder.setContentText(String.valueOf(Timecount));
                    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (NotificationCounter !=null){NotificationCounter.cancel();}
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            if (NotificationCounter !=null){NotificationCounter.cancel();}
            if (notificationManager != null) {notificationManager.cancel(1);}
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

> Способ заключается в том, что таймер ежесекундно записывает в текст
>   уведомления оставшееся количество секунд таким образом:
>   `builder.setContentText(String.valueOf(Timecount));` и обновляет
>   старое уведомление, запуская новое, таким образом: `notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());`

**Проблема:** Проблема заключается в том, что эти манипуляции ежесекундно увеличивают потребление MEMORY примерно на 0,10 МВ

**Вопрос:** Как избавиться от проблемы и держать потребление памяти на одном уровне при выполнении данной задачи?

Comment: Зачем это вам? Сервис падает по OutOfMemoryError? Виртуалка сама очистит память когда к лимиту подойдет.

Comment: И вам не отменять текущее уведомление нужно, а обновлять FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: @РусланЯгупов Исключительно ради экономии. До OutOfMemoryError ещё не доводил, но и что-то не замечал, чтобы виртуалка чистила что-то, хотя уведомление съедало уже прилично MB. За поправку - спасибо.

Comment: Часто бывает когда памяти много занимает, а потом вес мусор чистит. Бывало до 300мб и потом чистит до 200-150